# UIStackView's subviews have intrinsic size, yet still ignore content hugging priorities

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to programmatically create a stack view with a fill distribution that allows me to choose which subview stretches to fill the extra space, but so far I can't seem to control which view is expanding.

```
class ShelfVC: UIViewController {

    let shelfContentView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(shelfContentView)
        shelfContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        shelfContentView.layoutEqualTo(view: view)
        shelfContentView.spacing = 16

        shelfContentView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        let shelfMargin = CGFloat(16)
        shelfContentView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: shelfMargin, leading: shelfMargin, bottom: shelfMargin, trailing: shelfMargin)
        
        createTestBlocks()
    }

    func createTestBlocks() {

            let view1 = UIView()
            shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
            view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            view1.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            view1.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

            let view2 = UIView()
            shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view2)
            view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            view2.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
            view2.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
            
            let view3 = UIView( )
            shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view3)
            view3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            view3.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            view3.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see this:

[image]

But instead, I see this:

[image]

Why does the blue view stretch when it's hugging priority is higher than the purple view?

Answer (score 2):

Content Hugging Priority is not the same as Constraint Priority, and Constraints do not define Intrinsic Content Size.

Content Hugging (and Content Compression Resistance) Priority is based on **Intrinsic** content size.

You've given each view a **Width** constraint, and your stack view is using that to *begin* the arrangement. It then ***breaks*** one of the constraints because it cannot satisfy all of them.

You have two options:

- give the **constraints** different priorities
- give the views an **intrinsic content size** and set **Hugging** priority

Here is the first example:

```
class ConstraintHuggingShelfVC: UIViewController {
    
    let shelfContentView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(shelfContentView)
        shelfContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            shelfContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shelfContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shelfContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shelfContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        //shelfContentView.layoutEqualTo(view: view)
        shelfContentView.spacing = 16
        
        shelfContentView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        let shelfMargin = CGFloat(16)
        shelfContentView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: shelfMargin, leading: shelfMargin, bottom: shelfMargin, trailing: shelfMargin)
        
        createTestBlocks()
    }
    
    func createTestBlocks() {
        
        let view1 = UIView()
        shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
        view1.backgroundColor = .systemRed

        let wc1 = view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        wc1.isActive = true
        wc1.priority = .defaultHigh

        let view2 = UIView()
        shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view2)
        view2.backgroundColor = .systemPurple

        let wc2 = view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        wc2.isActive = true
        wc2.priority = .defaultLow

        let view3 = UIView( )
        shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view3)
        view3.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        let wc3 = view3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        wc3.isActive = true
        wc3.priority = .defaultHigh
        
    }
}
```

and here's the second example:

```
class IntrinsicView: UIView {
    var myIntrinsicSize: CGSize = .zero
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return myIntrinsicSize
    }
}

class IntrisicSizeShelfVC: UIViewController {
    
    let shelfContentView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(shelfContentView)
        shelfContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            shelfContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shelfContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shelfContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shelfContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])

//      shelfContentView.layoutEqualTo(view: view)
        shelfContentView.spacing = 16
        
        shelfContentView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        let shelfMargin = CGFloat(16)
        shelfContentView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: shelfMargin, leading: shelfMargin, bottom: shelfMargin, trailing: shelfMargin)
        
        createTestBlocks()
    }
    
    func createTestBlocks() {
        
        let view1 = IntrinsicView()
        shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
        view1.backgroundColor = .systemRed

        view1.myIntrinsicSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 0)
        view1.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        
        let view2 = IntrinsicView()
        shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view2)
        view2.backgroundColor = .systemPurple

        view2.myIntrinsicSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 0)
        view2.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        
        let view3 = IntrinsicView( )
        shelfContentView.addArrangedSubview(view3)
        view3.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        view3.myIntrinsicSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 0)
        view3.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

Both produce the identical layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`UIStackView` shrinks and expands using `.fill` based on the content compression priority if the arranged subviews don't fill the stack view. Thus, try changing `setContentHuggingPriority` to `setContentCompressionResistancePriority`.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/distribution/fill for more information on the `UIStackView.Distribution.fill` property.

Comment: You mean try changing `setContentHuggingPriority` to `setContentCompressionResistancePriority`?